# Should I use Material for Angular or Material for AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

[Angular's GitHub](https://github.com/angular) page shows two pinned repositories relating to Material Design:

1. [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2)
2. [angular/material](https://github.com/angular/material)

The [README.md](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/README.md) for [angular/material](https://github.com/angular/material) is titled **Material Design for AngularJS Apps**.

The [README.md](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/README.md) for [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) is titled **Material Design for Angular**.

I'm building an Angular2 web application using the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and have both *installed* and *imported* `@angular/material` into `app.module.ts`.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material'
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout'

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MaterialModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

I assume I should be following the documentation at [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/) and not [material.angularjs.org](https://material.angularjs.org/)?

Questions:

1. Can someone verify the following is correct?

   - [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) documented at [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/)
   - [angular/material](https://github.com/angular/material) documented at [material.angularjs.org](https://material.angularjs.org/)
2. Given that [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/) seems pretty (very?) limited in layouts, components, etc when compared to [material.angularjs.org](https://material.angularjs.org/), should I use [material.angularjs.org](https://material.angularjs.org/) in my application to take advantage of the numerous layouts and widgets, etc?
3. Can [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) be used with both?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When building an app with Angular (V2 or +), you should use [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) (github) and the doc at [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/).

Do not use [material.angularjs.org](https://material.angularjs.org/) as it is for AngularJs apps.

As you noticed, material2 doesn't have much to handle the layout and you should use [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) for that.

It's written in material2 repo Readme :

[image]

BTW, personal opinion here but it's great that they decided to split the layout from the components so even if you decide to use other components you can still have a responsive layout thanks to angular/flex-layout.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out which Material related projects were for Angular 1 and which were for Angular 2+. It saved me from some missteps.
  
Is it still true that Material doesn't have much support for layouts? There seems to be more layout support now. It it enough to remove the need to use the separate angular/flex-layout project?

Comment: Glad it helped! As you can see in [layout](https://material.angular.io/components/categories/layout) section from material doc, there isn't much related to layout. Unless you just want to use the grid list (which is probably not enough). So yes, you should stick with flex-layout.