# Selected options with md-select and Material Design for Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can a default (i.e. selected) option be set on a [Select component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/selec) when using [Material Design for Angular](https://github.com/angular/material2)?

```html
<md-select placeholder="Angular2 Material">
  <md-option>One</md-option>
  <md-option selected>Two</md-option>
  <md-option ng-selected="true">Three</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Searching SO lead me to:

- [Angular Material md select option group default selected values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714012/should-i-use-material-for-angular-or-material-for-angularjs)
- [md-select can't set selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881754/md-select-cant-set-selected-value)

I have tried both `ng-selected="true"` and `selected` attribute, neither work.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EyC6wpUpgZEihlGclDUU?p=preview

To be clear, I'm **not** using [Material Design for AngularJS Apps](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/). I am using [Material Design for Angular](https://material.angular.io/).

Comment: Go to https://material.angular.io/components/component/select. Read the section titles "Getting and setting the select value".

Comment: @JBNizet This is assuming I have a Component behind my form element. Although my Plunker does indeed have this, can I set a default from the mark-up to avoid having a component for each select element?

Comment: You always have a component. All angular views are views of a component. You don't need a component per select.

Comment: @JBNizet I do have components - but it's a parent component for the entire form. So I should set the default value in the component encompassing the form?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do. A form is typically used to provide information about an object (a user for example: name, first name, gender, etc.). That object is the model of the form. ngModel allows binding form widgets (like your select) to fields of your model (like your user object). So initialize the model (i.e. the user object), and the form fields will display the information of the user. That's basically what angular is all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have the variable to store selected value

```ts
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  myValue = 'Two';
}
```

then make sure the `md-option` has the `value` attribute. Bind the selected value via `ngModel`.

```html
<md-select placeholder="Angular2 Material" [(ngModel)]="myValue">
  <md-option>One</md-option>
  <md-option value="Two">Two</md-option>
  <md-option>Three</md-option>
</md-select>
```